# Angular getting more than 30 results

Tags: angular, restangular

I'm trying to get all data of one table and do an Excel of it. I have several problems. I'm using Restangular in my services. I did a getAll function in quotation.service.ts

```
getAll(): Observable<Quotation[]> {
    return this.rg.all('quotations').getList();
  }
```

And when I try to get it I do this in my component.ts:

```
exportAsXLSX(): void {
    this.quotationService.getAll()
      .subscribe(quotations => this.quotations = quotations);
    //console.log(this.quotations);
  }
```

When I try to access this.quotations it is undefined. I then tried:

```
exportAsXLSX(): void {
        this.quotationService.getAll()
          .subscribe(quotations => console.log(quotations ));
        //console.log(this.quotations);
      }
```

I get a result but I only get 30 results max when I want all of my rows (~1400) to do the Excel. I don't understand why I only get only 30 results and why when I try to access `this.quotations`, it is undefined.

EDIT: So the 30 max results was indeed because of the API. But I still have the problem where

> console.log(this.quotations);

is undefined, when I can check that quotations is the right data that I'm looking for.

The data from postman is something like this but I won't put everything since there is private data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "@context": "/api/contexts/Quotation",
        "@id": "/api/quotations",
        "@type": "hydra:Collection",
        "hydra:member": [
            {
                "@id": "/api/quotations/1",
```

Comment: Have you checked the API on some API client like postman, how many records the BE server is returning be default?

Comment: When I use postman with this url "/api/quotations/" I also get until id = 30, so 30 results

Comment: so you need to ask to the BE team, that how to fetch all the results, Are you the creator of the API or someother team?

Comment: I'm not the creator of The API, he has left now. Should I check in the API if there's something limiting the max fetch result? Where could it be? Our API is using Symfony.

Comment: this altogether a new question now, ask a new question with the BE code

Comment: I did another question that has solved my problem with the 30 results max, but I still have the error undefined, i edited my question.

Comment: post the response from postman here in your question

Comment: I edited with the response from postman

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally got it. I used

```
@Input() quotations: Quotation[];
```

in my component.ts when I should have used

```
quotations: Quotation[];
```

Works fine now.